# Razor view - emitting html outside Doctype tag

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to write a module/areas based mvc3 CMS using razor view engine. I have two layout views, _site.cshtml and _modules.cshtml. The _site.cshtml has an @RenderBody() section. My application always calls a view called "index.cshtml" which has its layout set to _site.cshtml page. 
**The Problem:** The problem is that my modules/areas are rendered before doctype element - and not inside the RenderBody section of layout page.

Comment: Can you post ~/Views/Shared/_Site.cshtml as well?

Comment: Well, that looks alright. Off the top of my head I wonder if the problem is the inherits statement causing it to think that the code you're displaying isn't the body for some reason.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what to tell you if it's not that. :( From what I'm seeing it should work. Have you tried making a really simple Hello World view and see if that works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, its your Invoke() method! The razor engine works by writing to an in memory stream, and then parses it to the response. The reason you are getting that behaviour is because your Invoke() method is writing straight to the response stream; i.e. before the in memory stream is parsed.

I came across similar behaviour when using the Html.RenderAction(), which pointed to an action that returned a PartialView. The workaround was to use Html.Action(). The difference being is that Action() returns a string which gets appended to the in memory stream, and RenderAction() writes to the directly to the response.

If you post the code for your Invoke() method, I may be able to help you futher!

| -- Edit -- |

OK, this turned out to be more complex that initially anticipated. The problem is that I could not get ProcessRequest() to append to the current response; however, I may have a solution.

```
public string ProcessRoute(ViewContext viewContext, RouteData routeData)
{
  var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(viewContext.RequestContext);
  var currentUrl = urlHelper.Action(routeData.Values["action"].ToString(),
    routeData.Values["controller"].ToString(), routeData.DataTokens);

  var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  var simpleWorkerRequest = new SimpleWorkerRequest(currentUrl, "", stringWriter);

  var context = new HttpContext(simpleWorkerRequest);
  var contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
  var requestContext = new RequestContext(contextBase, routeData);

  var httpHandler = routeData.RouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
  httpHandler.ProcessRequest(context);

  context.Response.End();
  stringWriter.Flush();

  return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

The code above generates a new Request and returns the Request's HTML as a string. By doing this, the result is appended as part of the current response. You can now rewrite your Invoke() function to return a string, which can be displayed on your View.

```
public string Invoke(ViewContext viewContext)
{
  if (_mvcHandler == null)
  {
    var routeData = new RouteData(context.RouteData.Route,
      context.RouteData.RouteHandler);

    routeData.Values.Add("id", _id);
    routeData.Values.Add("moduleName", _moduleName);
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", _controllerName);
    routeData.Values.Add("action", _actionName);
    routeData.Values.Add("pageContext", _pageContext);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_preferredNamespace))
    {
      routeData.DataTokens.Add("Namespaces", new[] { _preferredNamespace });
    }

    return ProcessRoute(viewContext, routeData);
  }

  return string.Empty;
}
```

You may also have to change;

```
mr.Invoke(ViewContext);
```

To;

```
Html.Raw(mr.Invoke(ViewContext));
```

In order stop the HTML encoding behaviour.

| -- Note -- |

Since I don't have your ModuleRequests class, I couldn't test this code specifically for your scenario. Instead, I replicated the problem as best as I could and solved it.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Matt

Comment: Hey - Can you make sure that you are outputting the response to the view? I did the same thing above when I was testing... i.e. Just because you call the function, doesn't mean you use it. The best I can describe it is expecting var testString = "hi"; to display on your page without telling it to. First, set a breakpoint on your Invoke() method and check what is returned; and second, use @Html.Raw() to display the result.

Comment: Thanks Matt for all your help - I have managed to fix everything.

Comment: That's fantastic news! Congrats! It was a good question, but you got there in the end! Your welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're trying to do is the equivalent of Html.RenderAction (or Html.Action), so why are you writing all that code yourself instead of using the built-in functionality?

Comment: The ASPX view engine replaces the text writer with a buffering one, but the Razor view engine does not. Any calls, directly or indirectly, to Response.Write will work correctly with ASPX but not Razor as a result. The reason this was done in ASPX is purely historical, to support controls which predate MVC.

Comment: Calling the entire MVC pipeline isn't trivial. I strongly recommend going with a design that allows you to use Action/RenderAction, or at the very least looking at the MVC source code to understand what Action/RenderAction does so that you can replicate it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post a plausible second alternative to your methods while I try and solve the problem above.

There is a html extension in MVC called Html.Partial(), which allows you to use routedata to return the result of a controller action.

So, if you had an AccountController with an Register method that returned a PartialView result, then it would be appended to the current page.

```
public class AccountController() : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Register()
  {
    return PartialView();
  }
}
```

The call to this action could look something like;

```
@Html.Partial("Account", "Register");
```

| -- Note -- |

Don't use @Html.RenderPartial(), or you will have the same problem as above!
I am currently posting away from a computer, so I can't test this theory!

Hope this helps!

Matt

Comment: Can I take a look at your OnSaveModuleSettings() method? Where are you getting your data from to save? and is it populated correctly? Thanks!